# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot receive primitive type(s) [int] in Corda

Tags: java, kotlin, blockchain, corda

I was trying to receive payloads back in PartyA(Initiator party) using receiveAll() function. But came across an error of :

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot receive primitive type(s) [int]** while executing the flow.

**Initiating Flow:**

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class sendAllMapReceiveAll_IntExampleFlow(private val itemToBeSent : String,private val item2 : Int) : FlowLogic<String>(){
    @Suspendable
    override fun call():String {
        val counterParty1 = serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName("PartyB",false).single()
        val counterParty2 = serviceHub.identityService.partiesFromName("PartyC",false).single()
        val counterPartySession1 = initiateFlow(counterParty1)
        val counterPartySession2 = initiateFlow(counterParty2)
        val sessionPayloadMap = mapOf(Pair(counterPartySession1,itemToBeSent), Pair(counterPartySession2,item2))
        sendAllMap(sessionPayloadMap)

        val receivedBack=receiveAll(Int::class.java, listOf(counterPartySession1,counterPartySession2)).map { it.unwrap { it } }

        return receivedBack.toString()
    }
}
```

**Responder Flow:**

```
@InitiatedBy(sendAllMapReceiveAll_AnyExampleFlow::class)
class SendAllMapReceiveAllAnyResponder(private val counterSession : FlowSession): FlowLogic<Unit>(){
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(){
        val payloadItem  = counterSession.receive<Any>().unwrap { it }
        println("PayLoad Received at Responder = "+ payloadItem)
        counterSession.send(12346)
    }
}
```

Later, in-order to solve this error. [I found this link helpful](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/1400). By changing **Int** to **Integer** in receiveAll() solved the issue. But **int** works in single receive function as given below:

```
val payloadItem  = counterSession.receive<Int>().unwrap { it }
```

1. Why does primitive int doesn't worked in receiveAll() but at the same time worked in single receive (session)?
2. Does other primitive types in kotlin also behave similar in receiveAll()?

**Edit**: Adding one more example which gave me the same error to solve the confusion in the answer.

```
val receivedBack2 =receiveAllMap(mapOf(Pair(counterPartySession1,String::class.java),
                Pair(counterPartySession2,Int::class.java))).map { it.value.unwrap { it } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code snippet that you provided is accurate.
The error message clearly mentions that you tried to receive a **primitive** `int` (lower-case `i`); while in your code you write the **class** `Int` (upper-case `I`).

I think initially you had `int` in your code and you got that error, then you changed it to `Int` when you posted the question.

`send()`, `receive()`, `sendAndReceive()` only work with classes (see documentation [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-flows.html#communication-between-parties)); so it will work with `Int` or `Integer`; it will not work with `int`.

Comment: Hi Adel I have rechecked this based on your answer. It is "Int" only, "int" gave me a reference error (In kotlin - Intelij) when I tried to use it.  receiveAll()  worked with "Integer" only. I will add another example to this question which gives me the same error.

Comment: Interesting, also it still gives the same error "cannot receive primitive [int]" when you use `Int` (upper-case `I`)?

Comment: yes. I have added receiveAllMap example also there. I am getting the same error for that as well.

Comment: Sorry Ben, not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: Yeah..I mean Integer works! So its fine for now. Just need to understand. https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/1400 this link helps me to use Integer instead! Thanks for the response, Adel!